# c++ multiset insertion error during debugging

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, multiset

I have noticed strange stuff during debugging of the following code:

```
#include<set>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    multiset<int> a;
    int n,curr;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>curr;
        a.insert(curr);
        for(auto k:a)cout<<k<<" ";
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Before this step everything is ok:

[image]

But after the 6th value is entered, in the debugger window **multiset a** contains only the values **4** for all `multiset` members, while the terminal output is correct.

[image]

My kit parameters are (C++11, GDB):

[image]

And operation system is:

[image]

Comment: FWIW, can't reproduce on Windows 7, Qt 5.9.4 (MinGW 5.3.0) and 5.12.4 (MinGW 7.3.0), QtCreator 4.10.1.

Comment: I can't reproduce this bug either, openSuse leap 15.0, GCC  7.4.1, GDB 8.2, and QtCreator 4.10.1

Comment: It may be a bug in GCC/GDB or in QtCreator. You aren't using any Qt class, so the Qt version is irrelevant. If the problem is in QtCreator, you have a simple solution: [download](https://www.qt.io/download) a newer version from qt.io; if the problem is with the compiler/debugger, then you may consider trying another Linux distro.